# How to get todays date in the same format as an existing date?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get todays date in the same format as my variable. The variable outputs the below:

> 2016-05-18T23:00:00.000Z

Where as this code below outputs the below:

> 1463152286532

```
 Date.now()
```

So the question is what do I have to do to  Date.now() to make it the same format as my first blockquote.

Answer (score 1):

The format you've shown at the top is the standard "ISO" format returned by `Date#toISOString` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)). So:

```
new Date().toISOString();
```

Note: `Date.now()` returns a *number*, not a `Date`. It's the number of milliseconds since The Epoch (Jan 1st, 1970 at midnight UTC).